# How can I hide field from standard Detail page?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

In sales force, without overriding page, can we hide fields from standard page.
I have a custom page which is added to a section in page layout and need to hide those fields which is shown in custom page from standard page because it appears twice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always remove them from the page layout? The same place where you have embedded the VF page in the first place.

Bear in mind that removing them from standard page layout will also remove them from new/edit screens, not sure if that's what you're after.

Advanced trick would be to hide them with Javascript that would fire only on "detail" pages. I wrote a bit about it in [May I customize 'edit custom object records' page layout on SalesForce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053278/may-i-customize-edit-custom-object-records-page-layout-on-salesforce/13104454)

Comment: Thanks eyescream for reply but we need to remove field dynamically means which field is dispaly on custom page then this field should not be display on standard page.....

Comment: That would mean use of JS to hide it on the parent page but it won't work across domains (VF pages aren't served from "*.salesforce.com"). You could still embed a JS function with this section header trick and from the VF decide whether to call it or not through the window.top... But it's very hacky.